# Disable OPCache temporarily

Tags: php, opcache

I recently moved to PHP 5.4 and installed OPCache, it's very powerful!

How can I temporarily disable the cache?

I tried :

```
 ini_set('opcache.enable', 0);
```

But it has no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Once your script runs, it's too late to not cache the file. You need to set it outside PHP:

- If PHP runs as Apache module, use an `.htaccess` file:

  ```
  php_flag opcache.enable Off
  ```
- If PHP runs as CGI/FastCGI, use a `.user.ini` file:

  ```
  opcache.enable=0
  ```

In all cases, you can also use good old system-wide `php.ini` if you have access to it.

Comment: Just a note: there is also an `opcache.enable_cli` option for command line php scripts.

Comment: I had to change php_flag to php_value (Ubuntu)

Comment: @dev101 Weird, because it's clearly [documented as boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.enable) :-?

Comment: Hmm, it is weird, first time I checked it caching was still active, now it is working. Could be that I hit wrong bookmark next to it.

Answer (score 29):

[opcache.enable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php) is **PHP_INI_ALL** which means that ini_set() *does* work, but only for current request to disable OPcache caching for the remainder of scripts compiled in your current request.  (You can't force enabling).  It reverts back to the system default for other requests.  By this stage, the request script will already have been cached, unless you do the ini_set in an [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.auto-prepend-file) script.

The system defaults (**PHP_INI_SYSTEM**) are latched as part of PHP system startup and can't be reread.  So in the case of Apache for example, you need to restart Apache to change / reload these.

The  `.htaccess` `php_flag` directives only apply if you are running mod_php or equivalent.  They and `.user.ini` files are PHP_INI_PERDIR, which will also be latched at request activation.

Now to the Q that I think that you might be asking.  If you have a dev system then the easiest way is to set `opcache.enable=0` in the appropriate INI file and restart your webserver.  Set it back to `=1` and restart again when you are done.

Also consider (in the dev context) setting `opcache.validate_timestamps=on` and `opcache.revalidate_freq=0`.  This will keep OPcache enabled but scripts will be stat'ed on every compile request to see if they are changed.  This gives the best of both worlds when developing.

Also read up on the `opcache.blacklist_filename` directive.  This allow you to specify an exclusion file, so if this contains `/var/www/test`, and the web service docroot is `/var/www` then *any* scripts in the `/var/www/test*` hierarchies will not be cached.

Comment: Is there a way to blacklist web_path, instead of filename? In Laravel, for instance, there is only one "bootstrap" PHP file for the whole application..

Comment: @pilat No. Blacklisting is based on the fully resolved file names of any files required or autoloaded, and not on the symbolic filename.  Since a URI will often load around 100 modules / files in the case of  complex app like a CMS or wiki, using the "web path" isn't meaningful.

Comment: If I get it right, you also can only disable in .user.ini files - not enable.

Answer (score 14):

The best way i found in my case for disable opcache in a specific PHP file is : `opcache_invalidate(__FILE__, true);`

You also can reset all cache with PHP :  `opcache_reset();`

Answer (score 1):

In my modest opinion, because I'm no expert, Jul has given the best answer. The question included the term "temporarily", so changing the configuration files I think... is not the best answer because you need to reconfigure, run what you want and reconfigure again to make it work normally.

It's not smooth.

With the answer of Jul you can modify the code to perform some action by disabling the opcache and return to a normal situation within the same code (although we would have to see how to re-enable from code the opcache)

For example, with Prestashop, there can be problems cleaning the "normal" cache from the administration interface if opcache is enabled, so in that case you can use a method so that when the action is performed, opcache is disabled, the "normal" cache is cleaned, and then opcache is enabled again.