# Codeigniter still loading deleted controller method

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been working with CodeIgniter for a while now and have never encountered this problem.

Basically, a function from a controller is continuing to load even though it no longer exists.

I do not have any caching mechanisms besides Chromes, and I have already hard reset to no avail. If you notice in the screenshot, it is throwing an error associated with the form validation library. I have already ruled out that it is CodeIgniter and it is definitely something I'm doing wrong but I am unable to see it.

I have claimed before that I did not think the problem was with CodeIgniter, but that was because I assumed the last version of my app was correctly working, but it is no longer working. Ill keep updating.

Okay so although I was only trying to send a single POST submission, there are hidden from elements as well as other visible elements on the forms that were definitely causing this issue. To give you a bit more information, this form is essentially a user interface for CURL. It is taking a website or any url as well as headers and attempting to download the version of the website into my database. I may have solved the issue but I can't say just yet until I pinpoint the problem I will mark the issue as solved.

So, I somehow fixed it.

This was my offending code : `echo form_input($value, set_value($value, $value));`

This is what I changed it to and it somehow worked : `echo form_input($name, $value);`

If you must know this is the start of the loop : `foreach (apache_request_headers() as $name => $value) {}`

[CodeIgniter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPNzl.png)

Comment: Clear the cache file and reload the site.

Comment: Just tried running CCLEANER to clear my entire Internet cache and it's still there. I do not employ any CI caching or anything else to cache any of the files.

Comment: I even tried renaming the file and the function name and it still does not change. I get the same exact message. The funny thing is I am getting the same string to be inserted into another field, yet I can't get it to work for this particluar, and apparently new controller and function.

Comment: FYI, I never do anything to the core of CI, I pretty much download a version, change the config settings and thats pretty minimal at that.

Comment: Try a different browser

Comment: Yes - I have tried firefox, but I am on the trail of the issue. I am looping through apache_request_headers() in PHP and echoing the output into a form input element, which I have found is my issue. Which exact value I am having an issue with is not yet clear. I think there is an issue here that is not necessarily my problem, but might be something with CI. I am NOT auotloading the form_validation library, yet when I try to submit something it is still performing a form_validation no matter what for variables I do not want to check for. If that makes any sense, sorry if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php).

Refer to this answer on [how to disable the opcache mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21556994/5189811).