# Wordpress, Virtualmin & PHP7: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-fcgid, php-7.1, virtualmin

I have a Wordpress installation on my server where I'm using Virtualmin with version PHP7 (main version) and PHP56 (secondary). The problem I'm facing is with the xmlrpc.php:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://example.com/xmlrpc.php?for=jetpack&token=sometokenhere
End of script output before headers: xmlrpc.php, referer: https://example.com/xmlrpc.php?for=jetpack&token=sometokenhere
```

This have been happening since I upgraded to PHP version 7. If I switch back to 5.6, the calls to xmlrpc works just fine.

When I ran `httpd -V` with a non-sudo user, I got the following error:

```
SuexecUserGroup configured, but suEXEC is disabled: Invalid owner or file mode for /usr/sbin/suexec
```

... and that was happening because of incorrect permissions, which were 510. I have changed permissions of `suexec` to `4755` and now it looks like this `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root apache 15352 Jul 19  2016 /usr/sbin/suexec` and the error is gone.

After this change, if I run `httpd -V` with a non-sudo user, I get a new error:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/mydomain_com/public_html] does not exist
AH00526: Syntax error on line 378 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Wrapper /home/mydomain_com/fcgi-bin/php5.6.fcgi cannot be accessed: (13)Permission denied
```

- Directory `/home/mydomain_com/public_html` exists
- Line 378: `FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain_com/fcgi-bin/php7.1.fcgi .php`
- Permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 mydomain_com mydomain_com 241 May  3 09:29 /home/butcaru_com/fcgi-bin/php5.6.fcgi`

This error occures when I run `httpd -V` with a user that isn't associated with a domain. If I login with `mydomain_com` user and run `httpd -V` the error isn't about `mydomain.com` anymore, is about another hosted domain (that doesn't have a Wordpress installation for any matter).

So this isn't something related to a specific domain/CMS. I think this is a misconfiguration of PHP7.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Jetpack's JSON API and PHP7 and it seems to be caused by opcache. Details on issue [here](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/issues/6629).

I have disabled opcache by creating a `.user.ini` file inside Wordpress's root dir containing the following line:
`opcache.enable=0`
and no more errors, Wordpress Android App works :)

*More on disabling opcache temporary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556437/disable-opcache-temporarily)*.