# Laravel project not refreshing views after changing codes

Tags: php, html, laravel

My Laravel project is not changing even after I have cleared and refresh everything.

I tried clearing the view, deleting the files manually.
I tried `cache:clear`
tried changing the root folder name too yet the project is still showing the older codes. Please help

Comment: Most likely an OPcache issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556437/disable-opcache-temporarily).

Comment: How to make it work? Sorry I dont have any idea

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you? It's all there.

Comment: Still not working. tried the php.ini and htaccess

Comment: How is your Laravel project being run? `php artisan serve`? Laravel Valet? Homestead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried command `php artisan view:clear`?

Also try to disable OPcache php extention.

Comment: how to disable the extension?

Comment: write `opcache.enable=0` in `php.ini`. Then restart Apache. Also you can add `php_flag opcache.enable Off` to `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you run the correct project, not anything else?

also, did you try this:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you change the code? What files?
This usually works for me.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```